# Rails auto loading files from wrong location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I see lots of

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant SomeModule::MyJob expected /app/lib/some_module/my_job.rb to define it.
```

errors in my Rails 5.2.0 application. The part I don't understand is, why it would look inside `app/lib/`, since it's defined to be loaded like this in the `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

So I would expect it to load from `/lib` (where the module in question is located). So why is it looking inside the `/app` directory and how can I change it?

Comment: I suggest you first print `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` to make sure `/lib` is not part of the autoload paths list.

Comment: @yoones It's not

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

to

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/*"]
```

it should work.